# Can't create an email alias in new Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

Our Google Apps has been updated to the new interface and I can't find where to create an alias for a user.  The help says to click User then on the user's name and then scroll down to the "add alias".  I don't see the "add alias" at all.  What am I missing?  My address has an alias because I set it way back when before the interface changed.  I have the grandfathered free version.  Do I need to upgrade?  I guess I can create a group email with one user but that only works for receiving email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work fine for me as described in this link - https://support.google.com/a/answer/182527

Click on profile and user profile appears on right and you have option to add alias there.

Comment: To be fair, the new design is FAR from intuitive. Under the description for the "Profile" heading it doesn't even mention Aliases, nor can you tell from looking over the interface that something is going to appear if you click that section. :rageface:

Comment: Yeah, the new Google Apps design really blows. Nothing looks like a link...but we're supposed to know to click on the word "Profile" to bring up a list of aliases? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The admin page was redesigned and it is not immediately evident how to bring up the old menus. After you log in to the Apps Admin interface and select a user you have to click the literal "Profile" block right underneath the user activity block. Once you click the actual word "profile" a fly-out menu is displayed to the right and you can add the alias again.

The Google help article could have been made more clear with a picture showing where to click now.

Comment: I cannot tell you how many times I clicked around that.  A picture would help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to click on. Hope it helps somebody as it's far from intuitive.

[image]